# The method is not allowed for the requested URL. in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I write this forum and I want to validate user name and password but I have result.Method Not Allowed

hello.html

```html
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>

</head>
{% if error %}
    {{ error }}
{% endif %}
<body>

      Hello 

</body>
</html>
```

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>welcome</title>
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <section id="content">
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required=""  name="username" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" name="password" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in"  />

            </div>
        </form><!-- form -->

    </section><!-- content -->

</div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

I write a forum:

in app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request
APP = Flask(__name__)
@APP.route('/')
def login1():
      return render_template('login1.html')
@APP.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
   return render_template('hello.html', error=error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      APP.debug=True
      APP.run()
```

I can't validate the input?
how can help me please

Comment: try `@APP.route('/?', methods=['GET', 'POST'])` to `@APP.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`.and in html ,`form action="/login"`

Comment: I have the same result

Comment: Did you changed in both `app.py` and `html` ?

Comment: yes I did what you said to me  @itzmeontv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code app.py code to the below, along with your current hello.html and login1.html this is working fine.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request
APP = Flask(__name__)
@APP.route('/')
def login1():
      return render_template('login1.html')
@APP.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error=None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
            return redirect(url_for('login1'))
        else:
           return render_template('hello.html', error=error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      APP.debug=True
      APP.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

First change the line in `app.py`

```
@APP.route('/?', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

to

```
@APP.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

And then in `login1.html`, change these lines to corresponding lines.

```
<form action="/login" method="post">

<input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" name="username" />

<input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" name="password" />
```

**Update**

```
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" name="username" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Log in"  />

        </div>
    </form><!-- form -->
```

**Update 2** `hello.html`

```
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>

</head>
{% if error %}
    {{ error }}
{% endif %}
<body>

      Hello 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I  changed but i have the same result: Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: which error ? The method is not allowed for the requested URL ?

Comment: Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand  @itzmeontv

Comment: CAn you update your `html` and `app.py` after your edit in your question ?

Comment: I don't undrestand what you means :( sorry

Comment: Why sory? :) ok.Please copy paste `html` form instead of your `html` fom in my `updated` answer.

Comment: no error but despite that I give different values for admin user name and password it goes directly to the hello page without displaying the error @itzmeontv

Comment: put you hello.html also in your question

Comment: I show request.form['username'] and request.form['password'] I always find that the content is none  which shows that it will not fetch the data I enter  in text fields

Comment: all the time it show Invalid Credentials. Please try again. Hello when the text fields true or false :(

Comment: Now update your question with latest updates :) , `app.py` and `html`s also

Comment: I found out that ,you still didnt copy paste my `form` to ypur html.Because in my form `<input type.........name="username">`, this `name=username` and `name=password` still didnt copied.Thats why you are getting `None` for `request.POST['username']` and those for password.

Comment: I find None because  I did  if request.form.get('username') != 'admin' or request.form.get('password') != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return render_template('login1.html')

Comment: Am told the reason in previous comment , why got None.Please read it completely and add `attribute`  for `input`.that is `name`.

Comment: in html, you are using `id=username`.So replace it `name=username` and for password, `name=password`

Comment: still if I give false data passes directly aficher hello without

Comment: What you expecting if True data, and for False data ?

Comment: true if the data has to go to another page and if not it should display an error in gold any case it goes without displaying an error hello if I enter false data

Comment: Did you want complete working program?am trying to do your own .

Comment: my goal from the start is to retrieve data for that I ask the question because if I try to retrieve the problems I find in any case thank you